# Copy formulae of range of cells to same range in other sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to copy the formulae of a range of cells to all other or selected sheets.

For example, I want the Formulae of Sheet1.A9:B250 copied to all other Sheets (SheetX.A9:B250)

I tried the following but it seems pretty off

```
Sub CopyAll()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Sheets("Albert").Range("A9:B250").Formula.Copy
For Each sht In Worksheets
sht.Range("A9:B250").Formula.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Is there an elegant solution to this? Thank you in advance

Comment: To all other workbooks or all other sheets? Your code seems to deal with sheets, if you want to copy to all other workbooks you need some kind of code to decide which workbooks shall be included.

Comment: Sheets, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Why not bypass copy and paste all together?
this should do the job

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:B250").Formula = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A9:B250").Formula
```

Your code would look something like...

```
Sub CopyAll()
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In Worksheets
    sht.Range("A9:B250").Formula = Sheets("Albert").Range("A9:B250").Formula
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with `Copy >> Paste` of formula you can use the following solution:

```
'.....
Sheets("Albert").Range("A9:B250").Copy
'.....
sht.Range("A9:B250").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
'.....
```